# В командной строке разработчика Visual Studio 2015 получаю ошибку

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

Собираю драйвер получаю это:
    Driver.c(11): error C2220: предупреждение обработано как ошибка - файл "object" не создан
Пишут что нужно убрать ключик /WX, либо добавить /wd4244, либо с помощью #pragma warning подавить это предупреждение в этом конкретном месте. Только вот я незнаю как это сделать. Вот моя команда что собирает драйвер:

```
msbuild /t:clean /t:build
```

Я пробовал добавлять туда /w и /property:WarningLevel=0 но не помогло

Comment: Вероятно, у вас имеется проект, созданный в Студии. Посмотрите наличие опции /WX в нем

Comment: А я там уже откл. Через студию компилируется, просто интерестно было через консоль.

Comment: Хм... А что тогда msbuild берет в качестве источника знаний для сборки?